# Roman to Integer (python) leetcode

Tags: python

worte a basic code for the problem but does not give correct answer for all the testcases
[Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/description/?envType=featured-list&envId=challenges-for-new-users)

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43t2b.png)

I think it doesn't go through the second set of if functions

Code-

`

```
    l=len(s)
    v=0
    a=-1
    vp=0
    while(a>=-l):
        v1=s[a]
        v2=0
        
        if v1=='I':
            v2=1
        elif v1=='V':
            v2=5
        elif v1=='X':
            v2=10
        elif v1=='L':
            v2=50
        elif v1=='C':
            v2=100
        elif v1=='D':
            v2=500
        elif v1=='M':
            v2==1000
        else:
            print("unknown")
        

        if v1=='I' and vp=='V' :
            v=v-v2
        elif v1=='I' and vp=='X' :
            v=v-v2
        elif (v1=='X')and(vp=='L'or vp=='C'):
            v=v-v2
        elif (v1=='C')and(vp=='D'or vp=='M'):
            v=v-v2
        else :
            v=v+v2
        a=a-1
        vp=v1

    return v
    print(v)`
```

Comment: @user2390182 he does, with `vp=v1` near the end.

Comment: The bug is `v2==1000` - it should be single equal sign to assign to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Some simpler logic:

- for every value

  - if followed by same or smaller value: ADD
  - else: SUBTRACT

```
from itertools imprt pairwise

values = {
    'I': 1,   'V': 5,
    'X': 10,  'L': 50,
    'C': 100, 'D': 500,
    'M': 1000,
}

vals = map(values.get, s+"I") # pad by min to give last value a "pair partner"
return sum((x, -x)[x<y] for x, y in pairwise(vals))
```